# Alternatives to Real Player

Tags: software-rec, media-player, realplayer

I'm looking for a program that can open Real Player files (.ram).  Real Player stinks, and I don't want to install it on my computer.  Unfortunately, I have to open some .ram files for an online class that I'm taking.  Are there any media players that can open Real Player files?

Comment: Is it an art class? That's the only justification I can think of for the juxtaposition of modern day technology with realplayer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking for an alternative to real player - check out [Real alternative](http://www.codecguide.com/download_real.htm).

Now that is good naming. You get exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: Was just about to suggest the same thing!

Comment: Real/QT alternatives would be my recommendations as well.  QT Alternative installs as a standard codec allowing replay in almost any standard media player so you can keep using your current app.  I believe Real Alternative does the same but haven't encountered a real media file in years so am not sure.

Answer (score 6):

Always has to be [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)!

It does say on their site only partial support for Real Player files, however I have not had a problem in the past.

Comment: VLC didn't work for me.  Still a great media player though!

Answer (score 2):

Either [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) or [Real Alternative Lite (with Media Player Classic)](http://www.codecguide.com/download_real.htm)

I personally recommend Real Alt. Lite with Media Player Classic. If you install Quicktime Alternative too, you can then open QT and Real files with Media Player Classic.

Some folks swear by VLC, I can't do anything with it. Not my taste!

Answer (score 1):

[Mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu) and its many front-ends can play Real files.

> MPlayer is a movie player which runs on many systems (see the
>   documentation). It plays most MPEG/VOB, AVI, Ogg/OGM, VIVO,
>   ASF/WMA/WMV, QT/MOV/MP4, RealMedia, Matroska, NUT, NuppelVideo, FLI,
>   YUV4MPEG, FILM, RoQ, PVA files, supported by many native, XAnim, and
>   Win32 DLL codecs. You can watch VideoCD, SVCD, DVD, 3ivx, DivX 3/4/5,
>   WMV and even H.264 movies.
>
> Another great feature of MPlayer is the wide range of supported output
>   drivers. It works with X11, Xv, DGA, OpenGL, SVGAlib, fbdev, AAlib,
>   DirectFB, but you can use GGI, SDL (and this way all their drivers),
>   VESA (on every VESA compatible card, even without X11!) and some low
>   level card-specific drivers (for Matrox, 3Dfx and ATI), too! Most of
>   them support software or hardware scaling, so you can enjoy movies in
>   fullscreen. MPlayer supports displaying through some hardware MPEG
>   decoder boards, such as the Siemens DVB, DXR2 and DXR3/Hollywood+.
>
> MPlayer has an onscreen display (OSD) for status information, nice big
>   antialiased shaded subtitles and visual feedback for keyboard
>   controls. European/ISO 8859-1,2 (Hungarian, English, Czech, etc),
>   Cyrillic and Korean fonts are supported along with 12 subtitle formats
>   (MicroDVD, SubRip, OGM, SubViewer, Sami, VPlayer, RT, SSA, AQTitle,
>   JACOsub, PJS and our own: MPsub). DVD subtitles (SPU streams, VOBsub
>   and Closed Captions) are supported as well.