# What is an efficient way to play .rm files?

Tags: realmedia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternatives to Real Player](https://superuser.com/questions/54307/alternatives-to-real-player)

I would like to play an .rm video once on a Windows machine. Should I actually download Real player? I would otherwise not use Real player, and it seems like a lot of memory usage just to play a .rm file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Install Real Alternative](http://www.filehippo.com/download_real_alternative/). This is a free Media Player Classic and Codec that will allow you to play RealMedia files (.rm .ram .rmvb .rpx .smi .smil) in Media Player Classic. It works great, and you'll never have to see that wretched RealPlayer again.Media Player Classic and the appropriate codecs are the solutions to ALL of your computer audio and video needs.

Comment: [Real Alternative + Media Player Classic download link.](http://www.filehippo.com/download_real_alternative/)

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/). The original Realmedia-Player always was crap (back in the days when I used it). Although VLC is relatively slim and simple, it plays a lot of different [file types](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_Features_Formats).

I have to add that .rm is only considered partially supported, but I don't remember having any problems.

Comment: VLC cannot play rm files by default; you need to install at least Real Alternative codec, and it may work in that way. VLC out of the box can play only RM stream files (audio).